# Will this config error stop apache from restarting

Tags: system-administration, apache, apache-config, httpd.conf

I have a production website running apache on linux.  There are all sorts of rules set up which I don't want to mess with.

I need to restart apache so I decided to do a configtest first to check that everything was ok.

My question is, will apache restart given this error?

```
>$ service httpd configtest
Syntax error on line 129 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt' does not exist or is empty
```

I didn't change the ssl.conf, I don't know who did, I don't know how to fix it.  Apache is running fine now.  Can I safely restart apache and expect it to come up?  If there were more errors than this one would they show - or does configtest stop after the first error?

Comment: eventually I decided to try to restart apache.  It did not let me restart.  I had to fix the error first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Apache hangs on any error, specially syntax errors.